# Button skin issue in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, mxml

I have created a button skin named HTMLBtnBlue.mxml, I created another skin with copy of HTMLBtnBlue.mxml and named it HTMLBtnYellow and changes up color to 0xF8C313. 
code for HTMLBtn.mxml is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo">

<fx:Style>
@namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
@namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo";

.upStyle {
    color:      #FF0000;
}

.overStyle {
    color:      #009900;
}

.downStyle {
    color:      #00FF00;
}

.disabledStyle {
    color:      #666666;
}

</fx:Style>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="up" />
    <s:State name="over" />
    <s:State name="down" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>

<s:Label
    id="labelDisplay"
    styleName.up="upStyle"
    styleName.over="overStyle"
    styleName.down="downStyle"
    styleName.disabled="disabledStyle"/>

<s:Rect width="100%" height="1" includeIn="over,up" bottom="0">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color.over="#009900" color.up="#0000FF"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

</s:Skin>
```

The code for buttons is as follows

```
<s:Button label="Open Menu" id="bluebtn" skinClass="skins.HTMLBtn" />   
<s:Button label="Close Menu" id="yellowbtn" skinClass="skins.YellowSkin" />
```

but it applies HTMLBtn skin to both Open Menu and Close Menu button.

Comment: I don't understand: is `YellowSkin` a subclass of `HTMLBtn`? How is this yellow color applied?

Answer (score 0):

Following your example above in Flash Builder 4.6 with AIR 3.4 :

```
    <s:Button id="bluebtn" label="Open Menu" skinClass="skins.HTMLBtnBlue"/>
<s:Button id="yellowbtn" label="Close Menu"  skinClass="skins.HTMLBtnYellow"/>
```

I had no problems with this.

```
   Skin Class "HTMLBtnYellow":

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo">

<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo";

    .upStyle {
        color:      #FF0000;
    }

    .overStyle {
        color:      #009900;
    }

    .downStyle {
        color:      #00FF00;
    }

    .disabledStyle {
        color:      #666666;
    }

</fx:Style>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="up" />
    <s:State name="over" />
    <s:State name="down" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>


<s:Rect width="100%" height="1" includeIn="over,up" bottom="0">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color.over="#009900" color.up="#F8C313"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>

<s:Label
    id="labelDisplay"
    styleName.up="upStyle"
    styleName.over="overStyle"
    styleName.down="downStyle"
    styleName.disabled="disabledStyle"/>
```

Skin Class "HTMLBtnBlue":

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <s:Skin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo">

<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo";

    .upStyle {
        color:      #FF0000;
    }

    .overStyle {
        color:      #009900;
    }

    .downStyle {
        color:      #00FF00;
    }

    .disabledStyle {
        color:      #666666;
    }

</fx:Style>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="up" />
    <s:State name="over" />
    <s:State name="down" />
    <s:State name="disabled" />
</s:states>

<s:Label
    id="labelDisplay"
    styleName.up="upStyle"
    styleName.over="overStyle"
    styleName.down="downStyle"
    styleName.disabled="disabledStyle"/>

<s:Rect width="100%" height="1" includeIn="over,up" bottom="0">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color.over="#009900" color.up="#0000FF"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
```

Comment: my issue has solved when I used label property color.up="#F8C313" instead of using styleName.up="upStyle"

Comment: Please post your answer as an Answer and mark it solved so that others might learn from your solution.